# Step Functions ignoring Parameters, executing it with default input

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I don't know if this is a bug of my own or Amazon's as I'm unable to properly understand what's going on.

I have the following Step Function (It's currently a work in progress), which takes care of validating an input and then sending it to an SQS lambda (CreateInAuth0 Step).

My problem is that apparently the SQS function is executing with the default parameters, fails, retries and then uses the ones specified in the Step Function. (Or at least that's what I'm gathering from the logs).

I want to know why it is ignoring the Parameters in the first go. Here's all the information I can gather.

There seems to be a difference between `TaskStateEntered` and `TaskScheduled` (which I believe it's ok).

```json
{
    "Comment": "Add the students to the platform and optionally adds them to their respective grades",
    "StartAt": "AddStudents",
    "States": {
        "AddStudents": {
            "Comment": "Validates that the students are OK",
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "@AddStudents",
            "Next": "Parallel"
        },
        "Parallel": {
            "Type": "Parallel",
            "Next": "FinishExecution",
            "Branches": [
                {
                    "StartAt": "CreateInAuth0",
                    "States": {
                        "CreateInAuth0": {
                            "Type": "Task",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken",
                            "Parameters": {
                                "QueueUrl": "@SQS_StudentsRegistrationSQSFifo",
                                "MessageBody": {
                                    "execId.$": "$.result.execId",
                                    "tenantType.$": "$.result.tenantType",
                                    "tenantId.$": "$.result.tenantId",
                                    "studentsToCreate.$": "$.result.newStudents.success",
                                    "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token",
                                    "studentsSucceeded": []
                                }
                            },
                            "End": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "FinishExecution": {
            "Comment": "This signals the ending in DynamoDB that the transaction finished",
            "Type": "Task",
            "End": true,
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
            "ResultPath": "$.dynamoDB",
            "Parameters": {
                "TableName": "@SchonDB",
                "Item": {
                    "pk": {
                        "S.$": "$.arguments.tenantId:exec:$.id"
                    },
                    "sk": {
                        "S": "result"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "S": "FINISHED"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "S": "@EXEC_TYPE"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        " States.Timeout"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                    "MaxAttempts": 5,
                    "BackoffRate": 2.0
                }
            ],
            "Catch": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.ALL"
                    ],
                    "Next": "FinishExecutionIfFinishErrored"
                }
            ]
        },
        "FinishExecutionIfFinishErrored": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the visual:
[image]

Here's the execution event history:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note: I have a try/catch statement inside the SQS function that wraps the entire SQS' execution.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `CreateInAuth0` should iterate over the students, and handle each student in parallel? That's not happening at the moment- you'd need dynamic parallelism for that. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/

Comment: @BertBlommers. That's intentional. The single lambda is going to handle all the students. But now that you mention it... Probably that's a much better way! Use a map and then have a single lambda handle a single student. This will also handle the retries and I wouldn't need to create a partial circuit breaker.

Comment: @BertBlommers Actually, thank you so much. That is a much better approach. The code has been greatly simplified. Just for general info, the parallel was going to be used to execute another task that was not yet defined. That's why it probably caught your eye.

Comment: Good to hear. Did it fix the original problem though, 'ignoring the Parameters in the first go'? I can't quite tell why that would happen in the original design

Comment: @BertBlommers It did!!! As I'm not using SQS anymore,  I don't know why either. But thank you so much! This approach is much better!